# Error "object is currently in use elsewhere" TFS GetLatest

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, tfs

We have our code available in TFS. When we take code in one machine (in a different location) it throws an error "object is currently in use elsewhere". Also one of the C# files is not getting downloaded. When we try to build it says "Source file 'filename' could not be opened ('Unspecified error')

This is not reproduced in other locations. Any idea what could be the issue?

Note: It is an asp.net website. We have used enterprise library. Also there is a chart control.

Note: We are using VS 2010.

I have read the following. But thge difference here is that the error is coming as and when we are taking latest from TFS. Is the TFS doing a build while taking latest itself?

[InvalidOperationException - object is currently in use elsewhere - red cross](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060280/invalidoperationexception-object-is-currently-in-use-elsewhere-red-cross)

also

[Error : Object is currently in use elsewhere.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824027/error-object-is-currently-in-use-elsewhere)

Comment: Maybe the file has been deleted and is no longer available in the repository, do you have a yellow icon seen next to the file in the solution explorer ?  Just check if the file is still there n the repository. Very much seems like the proj file is unaware that the file is gone ! !

Comment: I see a yellow icon. But the file is still available in the repository and it is working fine in our machines.

Comment: Are you running the application while you're trying to do a get?

Comment: No.. I am just trying to open the solution by docuble cicking on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If project solution name or some files have unique characters in names or some variable names in code other than basic latin letters, then sometimes moving the project would give these errors.

Comment: THe files have "." in names. Does that cause any issue? What do you mean by "moving the project"?

Comment: I got these errors like moving a project from one folder/location/computer to another. Sometimes this condition occurs committing/updating a file via source control system (repository etc.) to server.

Answer (score 0):

The first error seems like you are using some unmanaged code in your code base, so you would need to get the code in here which might help in why this is caused.

The second case is of the file being deleted from the repository and that .proj file on your machine has not been updated, so it complains of the missing file, you may have to remove it from your project for it to work. *one of the file is not getting downloaded* coz its not there in the repository at all

Comment: It is an asp.net website. We have used enterprise library. Also there is a chart control. The file is still available in the repository and it is working fine in our machines. This file is needed for the project to build

Comment: do you mean, it builds properly on your local machine ? do you have .proj in the repository maybe then the file is available local and not in the repository

Comment: It build properly in our (my location) local machines. The .csproj file is avilable in repository. We have more than ten developers accessing it in our environment. We always do 1) Undo pending changes 2) Delete local files 3) Get Latest