# Object currently in use elsewhere (System.Drawing)

Tags: c#, asp.net, system.drawing

This is the code which I run to generate a PDF

```
public string ScreenshotFullLength(string Url) {
    UrlScreenshot Shot = new UrlScreenshot(Url, 975, 100);

    int maxHeight = 1250;
    // If you do skip the crop function you 'll get the
    // full lenght of the page. We'll scale it to match
    // a 400 pixel width
    //int newHeight = (Shot.Bitmap.Width / 400) * Shot.Bitmap.Height;
    //Shot.Resize(400, newHeight);

    string Filename = LazyAssFilename();
    string path = Server.MapPath("~") + "/tmp/" + Filename;
    Shot.Bitmap.Save(path, ImageFormat.Png);

    string pdfURL = "";

    Document document = new Document();

    try {

        // step 2:
        // we create a writer that listens to the document
        // and directs a PDF-stream to a file
        pdfURL = Server.MapPath("~") + "\\tmp\\Attest_" + EOFName + ".pdf";
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(pdfURL, FileMode.Create));

        // step 3: we open the document
        document.Open();

        // step 4: we add content
        iTextSharp.text.Image jpg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(path);


        if (jpg.Height > maxHeight) {
            //we moeten er meer dan 1 maken en croppen
            int loops = (int)(jpg.Height / maxHeight);
            int rest = (int)(jpg.Height % maxHeight);
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
                Bitmap bmpImage = new Bitmap(path);
                Bitmap bmpCrop = bmpImage.Clone(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, i * maxHeight, 975, maxHeight),
                bmpImage.PixelFormat);

                iTextSharp.text.Image crpd = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bmpCrop, ImageFormat.Png);
                crpd.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Image.MIDDLE_ALIGN;
                crpd.ScalePercent(60);
                document.Add(crpd);
            }

            //the rest
            Bitmap bmpImage2 = new Bitmap(path);
            Bitmap bmpCrop2 = bmpImage2.Clone(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, i * maxHeight, 975, rest),
            bmpImage2.PixelFormat);

            iTextSharp.text.Image crpdRest = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bmpCrop2, ImageFormat.Png);
            crpdRest.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Image.MIDDLE_ALIGN;
            crpdRest.ScalePercent(60);
            document.Add(crpdRest);

        } else {
            jpg.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Image.MIDDLE_ALIGN;
            jpg.ScalePercent(60);
            document.Add(jpg);
        }

    } catch (DocumentException de) {
        Console.Error.WriteLine(de.Message);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        Console.Error.WriteLine(ioe.Message);
    }

    // step 5: we close the document
    document.Close();

    try {
        //screenshots deleten
        File.Delete(path);
    } catch { }

    return pdfURL;
}
```

This runs on a website, to make a PDF of a webpage. 
However when multiple people access this code from the website, to generate their PDF's, I get the error: `Object is currently in use elsewhere.`

STACKTRACE: at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams) at ...

How would I fix this? The error gets thrown at `Shot.Bitmap.Save(path, ImageFormat.Png);`

Comment: Aiiee! Never do `try { ... } catch {}` with no body, all kinds of strangeness will get caught there.

Comment: What type of Exception is it? Probably best just to post the full exception.ToString()

Comment: Ian: MESSAGE: Object is currently in use elsewhere. The problem is that i'm having a very hard time reproducing this error locally.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem, I have a worker thread pumping out GUI to its graphical interface, but it only throws this exception some of the time.
Wrapping it with an Invoke fixed it.

```
_parent.Invoke( new Action(() => eg.Graphics.DrawImage( _icon, rc )));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just spotted this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060280/invalidoperationexception-object-is-currently-in-use-elsewhere-red-cross). One of the answers suggests that GDI+ isn't threadsafe, in which case you'll need a lock around your Save() and maybe a few other methods.

Just to confirm, reading the information for the [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7e7b2kd.aspx) class, although it is ambiguous as to whether this means a single instance, or different instances of the same class.

> Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are
>   thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread
>   safe.